# Determine bases and the dimensions of $Ker(f)$ and $Im(f)$. Complete these bases to bases of $\mathbb {R}^4$ and $\mathbb {R}^5$, respectively.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb {R}^4→\mathbb {R}^5$ be an $\mathbb {R}$-linear map defined by $f(x, y, z, t) = (t, x+ 2y, y+z, z−2x, t+z+y)$.

Determine bases and the dimensions of $Ker(f)$ and $Im(f)$. Complete these bases to bases of $\mathbb {R}^4$ and $\mathbb {R}^5$, respectively.

> my take on the exercise:

$(t, x+ 2y, y+z, z−2x, t+z+y) = (0,x,0,-2x,0) + (0,2y,y,0,y) + (0,0,z,z,z) + (t,0,0,0,t) + (0,0,0,0,0) $

$= x(0,1,0,-2,0) + y(0,2,1,0,1) + z(0,0,1,1,1)+ t(1,0,0,0,1)$

$= <(0,1,0,-2,0), (0,2,1,0,1), (0,0,1,1,1), (1,0,0,0,1)>$

so the dim $Im(f)=4$

> is it correct so far?

$Ker(f)$ = {$(x,y,z,t)$ ∈ $\mathbb {R}^4$ | $f(x,y,z,t)$ = $(0,0,0,0,0)$}

$Ker(f)$ = {$(x,y,z,t)$ ∈ $\mathbb {R}^4$ | $(t, x+ 2y, y+z, z−2x, t+z+y)$ = $(0,0,0,0,0)$}

$Ker(f)$ = {$(0,0,0,0,0)$ ∈ $\mathbb {R}^5$}

so the dim $Ker(f)=1$

> I have trouble with completiting these bases to bases of $\mathbb {R}^4$ and $\mathbb {R}^5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute $\ker f$ by solving the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}t=0\\x+2y=0\\y+z=0\\z-2x=0\\t+z+y=0.\end{array}\right.$$Its only solution is indeed $(0,0,0,0,0)$ and therefore $\dim\ker f=0$. So, a basis of $\ker f$ is $\emptyset$. And, since $\ker f=\{(0,0,0,0,0)\}$, $f$ is injective and therefore $\dim\operatorname{Im}f=4$ and$$\{f(1,0,0,0),f(0,1,0,0),f(0,0,1,0),f(0,0,0,1)\}\tag1$$is a basis of $\operatorname{Im}f$.

Now, in order to get a basis of $\Bbb R^4$ which contains $\emptyset$, you can just take the standard basis. And it turns out that if you add $(1,0,0,0,0)$ to $(1)$, then you get a basis of $\Bbb R^5$.

Comment: yes, I omitted the step to put the system, I'm sorry. so the bases for $\mathbb {R}^4$ and $\mathbb {R}^5$ are $Im(f)$?

Comment: I've added another paragraph to my answer and I suppose that nothing is missing now.

Comment: okay thank you so much for the contribution! also for the $Im(f)$ should I prove that they are linearly independent?

Comment: Now, because when a linear map is injective, it maps linearly independent sets into linearly independent sets. So, the set $(1)$ is linearly independent.